# Can't bind to 'md-tooltip' since it isn't a known property of 'span', upgrading from angular material 2.0.0-beta.10 to angular material 2.0.0-beta.11

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have upgraded Angular Material from 2.0.0-beta.10 to 2.0.0-beta.11

As you may know, MaterialModule has been removed from this version. Now the problem is that I don't know how to import all the modules that was included in MaterialModule.

When I try to import the modules I need one by one, Chrome console gives me the errors like this: 
**"Can't bind to 'md-tooltip' since it isn't a known property of 'span'",**
even though in app.module.ts I have imported MatTooltipModule.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your component in the same module you imported the **MatTooltipModule**?

Comment: I've imported MatTooltipModule in the root module.

Comment: Is the component you're using the md-tooltip in in the root module as well?

Comment: Yes, it's in the root module as well.

Comment: Could you post the cod in your AppModule?

Comment: I have same issue with all directives from angular/material

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, just to be sure. In you app.module.ts you have imported Material Design modules like this:

```
import {
  MatSnackBarModule, MatSidenavModule, MatProgressBarModule, MatListModule, MatCheckboxModule,
  MatTooltipModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
   ...
  ]
```

Ah, i guess you forgot to rename everything from md- to mat-! Therefore, `md-sidenav` becomes `mat-sidenav`, and `md-tooltip` becomes `mat-tooltip`, etc.

See [the change notes](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta11-carapace-parapet-2017-09-21)